# bwplot in R: adding ticks to scale, reference line, and fill bars

Tags: r, lattice

I find it difficult to find help on lattice's bwplot, and after trying various things I thought I'll give asking a community a try. Hope there's someone experienced out there!

I have produced the [following plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBKpx.png),

[image]

and now I would like to:

1. add three more ticks to the y-axis (at 250, 750, and 1500 m)
2. add a horizontal reference line according to each of the six distances on said y-axis
3. colour five specific ID bars (F1, F2, F3, F5, and M1), preferrably in a light gray shade

This is the code so far, obviously there's some serious panelling missing. =S

```
levels(dp$period)<-c("Pre-Translocation", "Translocation")
bwtheme  <- canonical.theme(color = FALSE)
bwplot(DJL ~ id|period, data=dp, main="Day Journey Length",
   pch="|", xlab="ID", ylab="Distance (m)",
   par.settings=bwtheme)
```

Any help is greatly appreaciated!

Comment: Can you supply the data or a subset thereof? Typically you should use the dput command to generate a format which we can use to help you.

Comment: Agree. Read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example. You are much more likely to receive help with a minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: Thanks Andre, but the for loop seems not to work with bwplot().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a reproducible example, I load the sample data `singer` and start with a basic plot

```
bwplot(height~voice.part, singer)
```

1. add three more ticks to the y-axis (at 250, 750, and 1500 m)

   Do this by adding an argument `scales=list(y=list(at=c(250, 750, 1500))`. This is documented on `?bwplot`. For instance, here I place arbitrary ticks on my sample data by creating a variable `at` with the ticks at the desired location, then using these in the `scales` argument:

   ```
   at <- seq(60, 75, 2.5)
   bwplot(height~voice.part, singer, scales=list(y=list(at=at)))
   ```
2. add a horizontal reference line according to each of the six distances on said y-axis

   Do this by specifying a panel function that calls `panel.abline` and then `panel.bwplot`, as illustrated in the first example on the help page `?panel.bwplot`. I think you can also have success with the `grid` argument documented on `?bwplot`. Here we add lines at the coordinates specified by the variable `at` used in part 1.

   ```
   bwplot(height~voice.part, singer, scales=list(y=list(at=at)),
          panel=function(...) {
              panel.abline(h=at, col="gray")
              panel.bwplot(...)
          })
   ```
3. colour five specific ID bars (F1, F2, F3, F5, and M1), preferrably in a light gray shade

   From `?panel.bwplot`, use the `fill` argument to provide a vector of colors such that F1, F2, F3, F5, and M1 are gray, and the others white. Here I color the tenors gray by creating a variable `fill` of colours

   ```
   lvls <- levels(singer$voice.part)
   fill <- rep("white", length(lvls))
   fill[lvls %in% c("Tenor 1", "Tenor 2")] <- "gray"
   ```

   and using this in the plot

   ```
   bwplot(height~voice.part, singer, scales=list(y=list(at=at)),
          fill=fill, panel=function(...) {
              panel.abline(h=at, col="gray")
              panel.bwplot(...)
          })
   ```

Comment: Dear Martin, than you very much for your kind reply! You got me on the right track for 1. I had to adjust the ticks using tick.number (the 'at' function would somehow make my x-axis disappear). Am still struggling with the rest, have read all help pages about panel functions but could not get them to work...

Comment: @LeoTor I added more detailed answers; if you're still having trouble you should update your question with a [reproducible (toy) example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).